# SwiftUI TextField has a couple of seconds delay on first tap when testing with real iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Xcode version: 15.2 (15C500b)

iOS version: 17.2.1 (although in the last two updates before this one as well)

My device: iPhone 12

Easy to reproduce for me:

1. Create a new iPhone App project using Xcode
2. Write some code like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = "";

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")

            TextField("Tap me", text: $text)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

3. Run this on your real iPhone and tap on the TextField

I am getting a 1 to 2 second delay before focus, the cursor and the appearance of the keypad indicate that I can now type something. I also get this error on Xcode's console: `<0x101e0bac0> Gesture: System gesture gate timed out.`

I tried it with 2 textfields and once you experience the delay on the first tap, you can then switch between them instantly. Curiously, this doesn't seem to happen on the simulator at all.

Anyone know what this is about and how to fix it?

Comment: I see a delay when running under Xcode, but not if I launch the app directly on the device.  I would guess it is just an artefact of the debugging process.

Comment: Interesting. Now that I tried that, I also see that when launching directly on the phone I get no delay. Xcode debugging generally feels very slow both on my phone and Xcode itself on my M1 Pro macbook with 32GB RAM. What gives?